# Reorganizing loops for code's efficiency (repost, no satisfactory answers before!)

Tags: matlab, coding-efficiency

(Repost since I didn't get any satisfactory answers and it looks like no one care about it anymore)
Here's the problem

Consider the following function:

```
function A = plodding(N,d)
for ii = 1:N
   jj = 1;
   A(ii,jj) = randn;
   while abs(A(ii,jj)) < d
      jj = jj + 1;
      A(ii,jj) = randn;
   end
end
```

Rewrite this function to eliminate the allocation problem that is slowing it down. Call the new function, cruising. On a Dell Latitude E6410, with 7.8 gigabytes of usable memory, eliminating the allocation problem produces a speed-up factor of 7.

Here's my work:

The original version with rng(0)

```
function A = plodding(N,d)
rng(0); % To compare between the original and the modified version
for ii = 1:N
   jj = 1;
   A(ii,jj) = randn;
   while abs(A(ii,jj)) < d
      jj = jj + 1;
      A(ii,jj) = randn;
   end
end
end
```

The modified version

```
function A = cruising(N,d)
rng(0);
for jj = 1:N % Reorganize, so elems are added column-wise
   ii = 1;
   A(ii,jj) = randn;
   while abs(A(ii,jj)) < d
      ii = ii + 1;
      A(ii,jj) = randn;
   end
end
A = A'; % To get the matrix desired
end
```

But when I test (please look at the result carefully to understand my question)

```
>>tic;A = plodding(10000,2);toc
Elapsed time is 9.289355 seconds.
>>tic;A1 = cruising(10000,2);toc;
Elapsed time is 0.078783 seconds.
>>
>>tic;A = plodding(5,5);toc
Elapsed time is 1.168961 seconds.
>> tic;A1 = cruising(5,5);toc;
% When I posted this thread, it's already more than 10 mins and MATLAB's still "busy"!
```

Based on what I learned from the lesson, my logic should be right, because MATLAB stores elements column-wise. So in ANY case (either small or large N, small or large d), cruising should perform faster than plodding in ANY case. This behavior of MATLAB suggests that there's something about it that I still don't quite grasp. Can someone please help me???

Comment: @AndrewMedico not a duplicate

Comment: Whatever your previous question was of which this is a "repost", that isn't allowed.

Comment: You should edit your previous question adding any clarifications or updates rather than creating a new question. That will bump the question back into the New Question list.